# Python How to read string from file and insert into URL

Tags: python, command-line, raspberry-pi

I am trying to create an API call on a Raspberry-Pi with no GUI. The URL must have user specific credentials, these credentials will not change so am trying to write to, then read from a file and insert to the correct part of the URL.

WIP code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

system_id = raw_input("What is your Enphase System ID: ")
user_id = raw_input ("What is your Enphase User ID: ")

f1 = open ("enphase_system_id.txt", 'w+')
value1 = (system_id)
s1 = str (value1)
f1.write(s1)

f2 = open("enphase_user_id.txt", 'w+')
value2 = (user_id)
s2 = str (value2)
f2.write(s2)

url = ("https://api.enphaseenergy.com/api/v2/systems/"
       +f1.read()+
       "/summary?key=6ba121cb00bcdafe7035d57fe623cf1c&usf1c&usf1c&user_id="
       +f2.read())

print url

f1.close()
f2.close()

from urllib2 import urlopen

inverter = urlopen(url)

response = inverter.read()
body = response

print body
```

The problem is the URL is concatenated without the read strings:

https://api.enphaseenergy.com/api/v2/systems//summary?key=6ba121cb00bcdafe7035d57fe623cf1c&usf1c&usf1c&user_id=

Today is literally my first day programming in any language, your help much appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear: you are reading things from the console. writing them to open files, then trying to read them back out of those same open files?

Comment: Yes, I know the raw_input and reading form file is redundant, I aim to figure out how to not request raw_input if the files already exist.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed files after writing to them (to be precise, You closed them too late). That's first thing. Next, You need to open those files after closing them in order to read them. Also, You can simply do:

```
f1.write(value1)
f2.write(value2)
```

instead of

```
value1 = (system_id)
s1 = str (value1)
f1.write(s1)
```

and

```
value2 = (user_id)
s2 = str (value2)
f2.write(s2)
```

Comment: Thanks, I read that because the IDs were numeric, I would have to create them as strings before writing to the .txt file.

How do I insert the contents of the files, into the URL?

Comment: They are read as strings, no meter they are numeric. `raw_input` returns string. You are doing good thing with reading (`f1.read()`).

Comment: Ok thanks, it doesnt like the concatenation:
    +f2.read)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'builtin_function_or_method' objects
EDIT: Sorry I made a typo, all working now, thanks!